# Is it possible to remap <Super>d to do something other than show the desktop?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 GNOME edition. I'm trying to remap d to run rofi instead of showing Desktop, but when I try to remap the keybinding in the Keyboard Settings, it prompts me to enter the keybinding, and when I enter d, it shows the desktop, and I am unable to bind the key to run rofi.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to disable the existing keybinding of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, which in Ubuntu is bound to "Hide all normal windows" (i.e., Show the desktop).

In "Settings" - "Keyboard", look for "Hide all normal windows" under the section "Navigation". Click the line, then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove the binding. Now, you can set a custom keybinding to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> clicking "+" in the section "Custom keybindings".